# Angular4 Web Worker application not displaying

Tags: angular, typescript, web-worker

I have a website that is heavy on CPU usage that I decide to port to web workers.

I have followed this step by step tutorial: https://medium.com/@enriqueoriol/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135

I have cloned this rep and made it seem identical: https://github.com/kaikcreator/angular-cli-web-worker

I encountered a few issues where the document was not defined or the window. In these cases I tested on the github rep if its a problem with or with the module and it was the module so I removed them.

Basically I have no error right now and the page simply doesn't display:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/16fb37d75a85e9f387434ff1713640d2.png]

I assume it is because Angular has no way to access the window object so it can't inject the code.

**My app.module complained about lacking platform location providers so I added:**

```
import { WORKER_APP_LOCATION_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/platform-webworker';
```

**while replacing the BrowserModule with the WorkerAppModule**

Here is my main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapWorkerUi } from '@angular/platform-webworker';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapWorkerUi('webworker.bundle.js');
```

My workerLoader.ts

```
import 'polyfills.ts';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';

import { platformWorkerAppDynamic } from '@angular/platform-webworker-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformWorkerAppDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

My webpack config is: https://gist.github.com/misha130/9a21e1c08ca9e0bf79635dedc3279b2d

What could be the problem that stops it from rendering the page?

**EDIT**: After investigation this caused the problem and the usage of the router module causes the problem for me. How do I use PlatformLocations and RouterModule and Web Workers?

Answer (score 2):

I was also referencing the [Angular with Web Workers: Step by Step](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135) post on Medium (as did the OP). [One of the comments on that post](https://medium.com/@JasonRolaveric/hi-enrique-oriol-288d93282fde) mentioned including `WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS` and `WORKER_APP_LOCATION_PROVIDERS` into your application.

In your main.ts, add `WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS` as the second argument of `bootstrapWorkerUi()`

```
...
import {
  bootstrapWorkerUi,
  WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS
} from '@angular/platform-webworker'
...

bootstrapWorkerUi('webworker.bundle.js', WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS);
```

In your AppModule, add `WORKER_APP_LOCATION_PROVIDERS`. I also needed to provide a value for base href (which I've included below)

```
...
import {
  WorkerAppModule,
  WORKER_APP_LOCATION_PROVIDERS
} from '@angular/platform-webworker';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    WorkerAppModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '/'
    },
    WORKER_APP_LOCATION_PROVIDERS
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

That should get you past your PlatformLocation provider problem, and maybe even your future base href problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I linked the same blog post in the question you know but the comment was interesting. I eventually got passed this but stumble on to many many other problems. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Edited my answer to show that. I stumbled on your question after going through a lot of issues myself, didn't read your questions thoroughly. Sorry about that!