# Angular - webpack config for web worker in angular6

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular6, web-worker

i tried to run my angular6 web application in a web worker as described [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135)

because of lack of `ng eject` in angular6 , i use [this](https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21) to create a custom webpack config file.

**workerLoader.ts**

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';

import { platformWorkerAppDynamic } from '../node_modules/@angular/platform-webworker-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformWorkerAppDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapWorkerUi,WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/platform-webworker';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';



if (environment.production) { 
  enableProdMode();
}


bootstrapWorkerUi('webworker.chunk.js',WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';
import {
  WorkerAppModule,
  WORKER_APP_LOCATION_PROVIDERS,
  WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS
} from '@angular/platform-webworker';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   // some components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    //some imports
    WorkerAppModule,

  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '/'
    },
    WORKER_APP_LOCATION_PROVIDERS
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');


module.exports = {
    "entry": {
        "main": [
          "./src/main.ts",
        ],
        "polyfills": [
          "./src/polyfills.ts"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "./src/styles.css"
        ],
        "webworker": [
          "./src/workerLoader.ts"
        ]
    }
  ,
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
},

 optimization: {
     splitChunks: {
         cacheGroups: {
             commons: {
                 test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                 name: 'vendor',
                 chunks: 'all'
             }
         }
     }
 },

}
```

the problem is after going in browser , i get an error `webworker.chunk.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined` and the line create this error is 
 `(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["webworker"],{`

i find a same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715932/angular4-web-worker-application-not-displaying/47358269#47358269) , but not worked for me .

how to solve the problem?

**update**:
my question marked as a possible duplicate , but  i referred to that question myself and emphasized that not worked for me.

**update**:
AFAIK a web worker doesn't access to global variables such as `window` and the error is somehow weird because want to access `window` in a web worker . i think a misconfiguration in webpack config file is the reason of the error .
[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEJV7.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular4 Web Worker application not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715932/angular4-web-worker-application-not-displaying)

Comment: as i said , that did not worked for me , and i Deliberately referred to that question

Comment: but the question itself it still a duplicate

Comment: i do what explained there and my problem is still exist , what should i do ?

Comment: @aimar can you give me the steps to implement web worker in angular 6. Becz I am struggling for past 2days. I went through this https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135 but can't able to use ng eject

Comment: Also I have posted one questions in stackverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029035/web-workers-in-angular-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error, I solved it by adding the following option to customWebpackConfig in angular.json:

```
"mergeStrategies": {"optimization":"replace"}
```

I hope that helps

see [related gitHub issue](https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/issues/13)

Comment: i tried to solve my problem , but i Encounter the same errors In the following , and different behaviour of different minor versions of angular6 also on different systems , and finally i frustrated. how much improved performance for you ? and did you encounter any error until now?

Comment: another problem is that webpack config does not work with "ng serve" , how could you fix this?