# Web workers in angular 6

Tags: angular, web-worker, angular-forms, formarray

I am using angular 6. I want to load 100 rows in my grid but this 100rows contains lots of data so while loading this data in my angular application it's hangs the browser.

So currently I changed into 20rows per page I am using remote pagination.

But I have a requirement to load 100rows in my application. So I tried to implement the WebWorkers. But I didn't find any examples.

Can someone give me the example or steps to implement WebWorkers in angular 6

Also I am using reactive formarray for dynamic forms. In this I am loading more than 50 drop-down fields on edit form that time also browse hangs. I need a solution for this formarray also.

Comment: You are probably looking for a virtual scroll component, you can find one [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/scrolling/scrolling.md)

Comment: @Ploppy I want some example to implement web workers in angular 6

Comment: It's not that simple, that's why I recommend you to implement a virtual scroll strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a useful presentation that talks about integrating web workers in your angular application:

[SlideShare :- Web workers in your Angular Application- Different Approaches](https://www.slideshare.net/SureshPatidar2/web-worker-in-your-angular-application)

[Github :- Sample Code from presentation for Web Worker in Angular 6](https://github.com/patidar-suresh/angular6-webworker)

[Article :- Running your Angular 6 application in Web Worker](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-web-workers-angular-6-app-generated-angular-cli-suresh-patidar/)

Hope these links will be helpful for you to understand different approaches for using web worker in angular app and choose the one that best fit for your project and use case.

Comment: Thank you @Suresh Patidar. I have tried to implement this solution my application but it's for specific thread. How I can implement for whole angular application. I need to run whole application in web workers.

Comment: The article link mentioned above talks about this only i.e how to run the whole angular application in a web worker thread. For this to work your application should not have any direct reference to DOM, Window, and Document object in components and services code because you can't access these objects from worker thread.

Comment: I am rendering 100rows per page(it's a requirement) in table that time browser getting hanged. Is there any other solutions to increase the performance.

Comment: Rendering 100 rows should not be a problem unless you are doing any CPU intensive processing on the data received. I would recommend first do some kind of profiling of your application to locate the problem. You can use console.time and console.timeEnd API to see which section of the code is taking more time in processing. Once you find the culprit then you can move that logic to run in a web worker using one of the approach mentioned above.